# What does sess_herd means?

Tags: varnish

Using varnishstat, the metric 'sess_herd' is increasing a lot, during trafic and it seems that I've maybe reached some a limit (300 sess_herd / s)

I think, I got no backend issue (all busy, unhealthy, retry, failed at 0).
Backend_req/Client_req is around 150 req/s.

Right now, our Varnish isn't caching at all, it is just "proxying" to our backend server. So the "pass" rates is about 150 req/s

What could explain such a sess_herd ?

[Session_herd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWvgL.png)

Regards

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

Session herding is a counter that indicates when an ongoing session (TCP-connection) is handed off the worker thread and to a waiter that keeps it while the client thinks.

By default a connection get to keep its worker thread for 50ms (timeout_linger parameter in 4.1) before this happens.

Since networks and clients are slow, a worker thread can in that way serve a whole lot of clients. This reduces the number of running threads needed.

In practice this happens after a response has been sent and while waiting for another request on the reused connection.